# Why won't this work ? Dynamic memory beginner program

Tags: c, file, dynamic, malloc, realloc

```
int main()
{   
    //FILE *out = fopen("keimeno.txt", "w+");

    FILE *in = fopen("keimeno.txt", "r");
    int fullbufflen=0 , i;

    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, in);

    int bufflen = strlen(buffer);
    char *text;
    text =calloc(bufflen,sizeof(char));
    char *strcat(text, buffer); 
    //  printf("line of \"keimeno.txt\": %s", buffer);
    //  printf("size of line \"keimeno.txt\": %i\n\n", bufflen);

    fullbufflen = bufflen;  

    while(fgets(buffer, 100, in)!=NULL)
    {         
        //  printf("line of \"keimeno.txt\": %s", buffer);
        //  printf("size of line \"keimeno.txt\": %i\n\n", bufflen);
        text =realloc(text,bufflen*sizeof(char));
        char *strcat(text, buffer);

        fullbufflen = bufflen + fullbufflen ;
    }
    for (i = 0;i<fullbufflen;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",text[i]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to copy the full text file (keimeno.txt) into a dynamic memory array, with a buffer of 100 character at most everytime. To test it at the end i tried to prinf the results. And i just cant get it to work. Dont know if there is a problem on the printf at the end, or the whole program is just wrong.

Also the dynamic array is supposed to have 0 size at the beggining, so if someone could tell me how to do that too, it would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is that `char *strcat(text, buffer); ` line?

Comment: Your `calloc()` is wrong for 2. 1. You need to allocate 1 extra byte for the terminating `nul` byte. 2. You don't really need `calloc()` you need `malloc()`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm .Am i using this completely wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

```
char *strcat(text, buffer);
```

This is not how you call a function.  This is a function declaration, and an incorrect one at that since it doesn't define the types of the arguments.

To call `strcat`, just do this:

```
strcat(text, buffer);
```

Next, you're not allocating enough space for your buffers:

```
text =calloc(bufflen,sizeof(char));
```

You need to add space for the null bytes that terminates the string:

```
text =calloc(bufflen + 1,sizeof(char));
```

Similarly here:

```
text =realloc(text,bufflen*sizeof(char));
```

This only reallocates a total of `bufflen` bytes.  It does not add `bufflen` bytes to what was already allocated, and `bufflen` is unchanged from when it was first set outside of the `while` loop.  Do this instead:

```
bufflen = strlen(buffer);
text =realloc(text,bufflen+fullbufflen+1);
```

This gives you enough space for the current length, the additional buffer, and the null byte.

Finally, make sure you `fclose(in)` and `free(text)` at the end to clean up your resources, and be sure to check the return value of `fopen` to ensure that the file opened successfully, and `realloc`/`calloc` to ensure that your allocations worked.

After the above changes, you code should look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    //FILE *out = fopen("keimeno.txt", "w+");

    FILE *in = fopen("keimeno.txt", "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        perror("open failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    int fullbufflen=0 , i;

    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, in);

    int bufflen = strlen(buffer);
    char *text;
    text =calloc(bufflen+1,sizeof(char));
    if (text == NULL) {
        perror("calloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcat(text, buffer);
//  printf("line of \"keimeno.txt\": %s", buffer);
//  printf("size of line \"keimeno.txt\": %i\n\n", bufflen);

    fullbufflen = bufflen;

    while(fgets(buffer, 100, in)!=NULL)
    {
    //  printf("line of \"keimeno.txt\": %s", buffer);
    //  printf("size of line \"keimeno.txt\": %i\n\n", bufflen);
        bufflen = strlen(buffer);
        text =realloc(text,bufflen+fullbufflen+1);
        if (text == NULL) {
            perror("realloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcat(text, buffer);

        fullbufflen = bufflen + fullbufflen ;
    }
    fclose(in);
    for (i = 0;i<fullbufflen;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",text[i]);
    }
    free(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much just for putting on the effort .This works almost perfect but from what i can see it only displays some part of the whole text ,in the txt file i have a text about 600 chars and it will only display 300 or something. I find this strange cause since it works and the buffer is 100c , why would it get stuck in such a number ?

Comment: @begginer3 I ran this source code through the program and it read and wrote the whole thing.  The way it's printing, it outputs one character per line, so it might be difficult to see.  Try taking out the `\n` in the `printf` at the end and see what the output looks like.

Comment: There are a number of issues with this attempt.  (1) No error checking.  (2) long input lines are a problem. (3) main signature is wrong

Comment: @JohnHascall Long lines aren't a problem.  The next call to `fgets` will pick up where it left off.  I tested with lines longer that 100 characters and it still works.  I did change the `main` signature and added errors checks to `fopen` and `calloc`/`realloc`.

Comment: @JohnHascall could you please elaborate so I can fix them ?

Comment: @dbush YOU ARE RIGHT .THANK YOU VERY MUCH AND HAVE A NICE DAY. its caps cause I am happy .

Comment: @begginer3 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I think you have most of them fixed.  One remaining issue is (quoting the Linux man page) `... fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


#define ERR     (-1) 
#define GROW    100


static void die ( const char * msg ) { perror(msg); exit(1); }


int main ( void ) {

        char *  filename        = "in.txt";
        size_t  buffSize        = 0;
        size_t  buffUsed        = 0;
        ssize_t bytesRead       = 0;
        char *  buffer          = NULL;
        char *  tmp;
        int     fd;

        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
        if (fd == ERR) die("open");

        do {
                buffUsed += (size_t)bytesRead;
                if (buffUsed == buffSize) {
                        tmp = realloc(buffer, buffSize += GROW);
                        if (tmp == NULL) die("realloc");
                        buffer = tmp;
                }
                bytesRead = read(fd, buffer + buffUsed, buffSize - buffUsed);
                if (bytesRead == ERR) die("read");
        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, buffUsed) == ERR) die("write");
        free(buffer);
        if (close(fd) == ERR) die("close");

        return 0;
}
```

Like the original, the input filename is hard-coded which sub-optimal...

Comment: thanks for the effort but i feel like this would seems to much to my professor cause we have not touched at all some of the stuff you have been using. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, if this is an assignment, you should definitely turn in your own work, but feel free to pick up some pointers for your future assignments: (1) Check for Errors, (2) Use the proper variable types, (3) Don't stick 'magic' numbers in your code, use #defines, (4) White space aids in readability, (5) Compile with warnings turn ON

Comment: thanks for the advice , but what would you mean with 'magic' numbers ,give me an example so i can fix it.

Comment: Pretty much any number besides 0, 1 and infinity is "magic" number. Imagine reading through somebody else's code and seeing `ipy = 1512;` that's a magic number. What does it mean? Who knows? But if you see `ipy = INNINGS_PER_YEAR;` then that starts to make some sense as soon as you see it.